Addition operator for templatized aggregates
I made a class Point which can be 1D or 2D.
First, here is the code (it is compilable in C++17 on any online compiler):
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class Axis : uint8_t { XCoord, YCoord, NoCoord };

template <Axis T>
struct PointMember;

template<>
struct PointMember<Axis::NoCoord>
{
};

template<>
struct PointMember<Axis::XCoord>
{
    int x;
};

template<>
struct PointMember<Axis::YCoord>
{
    int y;
};

// We can instantiate for only one dimension, but if we instantiate for both,
// XCoord must be used for first template parameter, and YCoord for the second one.
template <Axis T, Axis U = Axis::NoCoord, typename Enable = void>
struct Point;

template <Axis T, Axis U>
struct Point<T, U, std::enable_if_t<(static_cast<uint8_t>(T) < static_cast<uint8_t>(U))>> :
    PointMember<T>, PointMember<U>
{
};

using Point2D = Point<Axis::XCoord, Axis::YCoord>;


int main()
{
    Point<Axis::XCoord>                x_point { 1 };
    Point<Axis::YCoord>                y_point { 2 };
    Point<Axis::XCoord, Axis::YCoord> xy_point { 1, 2 };

    return 0;
}

Now, I need to add the basic arithmetic operators, ie:
    template <>
    PointMember<Axis::XCoord> operator+(const PointMember<Axis::XCoord>& lhs, const PointMember<Axis::XCoord>& rhs)
    {
        return PointMember<Axis::XCoord>(lhs.x + rhs.x);
    }

Same for YCoord, and even easier for NoCoord (I just return a new instance, without any operation).
But I don't find a way for Point, because I don't know what to give to the constructor (especially because the number of arguments may be one or two according the T and U types).
EDIT: I just want to be able to do operations between two points of same type.

I don't understand your intentions here. If I understand your example plus operator, Point2D{1,2} + PointMember<Axis::XCoord>{5} == PointMember<Axis::XCoord>{6}. (we lose the y axis) And if we add two points with different axes (eg XY + XZ) we would also get back just the X axis???

Perhaps you should start with the simplest case: adding two Points with identical axes.

I just want to be able to add Point1D to Point1D and Point2D to Point2D.

So what stops you from writing just that?

I'm not sure the juice is worth the squeeze.  I'd make struct PointX, struct PointY, and struct PointXY and dispense with the templates.  After that works, and you feel that you can extricate the commonality into a template, then using PointX = PointMember<Axis::XCoord>; or struct PointX : PointMember<Axis::XCoord> and the rest of the code wouldn't have to change.

@Botje As said in the original post: I don't know what to give to the contrusctor. Just try to code operator+.

Side note: the empty instanstance will be second base to point which will occupy at least one byte(more due to alignment). If it could be the first, empty base optimization could be present.

@Oodini Point2D operator+(const Point2D& left, const Point2D& right) { return Point2D{left.x + right.x, left.y + right.y}; } surely?

@Red.Wave I don't think so, tahnks to empty base optimization.

@Botje Yes, but I as looking for an generic solution.

Replace Point2D with Point<T, U> and parameterize the operator+ free function over T and U, stipulating that U is not equal to Axis::NoCoord. I still don't get what all this mental masturbation is buying you over struct Point { int x,y; }

@Botje The purpose is to find a generic way to define operators, so that I don't have to define each operator three times (for Point<AxisX, AxisY>, Point<AxisX>, andPoint<AxisY>).
